# Redundant Hostnames Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics notices a unsolve the problem **Redundant Hostnames**:

Property http://www.domain.com is receiving data from redundant hostnames:

The old tracking code is still using to track and the website does not use  Universal Analytics tracking code, yet.

We have the large website and Google Analytics is a small portion of the website team. We are still get information for the which servers in the the webpage.

Is it possible to quick fix the redundant hostnames notification in Google Analytics?

Comment: You can view this blog post along with a video tutorial on how to do this here
https://www.tutlinks.com/301-redirect-non-www-to-www-resolve-redundant-hostnames/

Answer (score 2):

I have walking through this issue which i discovered today in my Anayltics account! Anyway i have found a good solution for **Normal websites** and **WordPress based blogs**.

**First for normal website(s):**

1. Open your website root .htaccess file and paste this code:

   `RewriteEngine On (if this line exists, then don't add this line again).`
    
   `# Rewrite all requests to the 'www' version`
   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]`
   `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

**Second for WordPress Based Blog(s):**

1. Open your website root .htaccess file and paste this code:

   `# BEGIN WordPress`
    
   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
    
   `RewriteEngine On`
    
   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$ [NC]`
    
   `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`
    
   `RewriteBase /`
    
   `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`
    
   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
    
   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
    
   `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`
    
   `</IfModule>`
    
   `# END WordPress`

> Please note that you have to change "yourdomain" with your actual domain name.

Thank you and hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

The redundant hostnames notification in Google Analytics will appear when two or more variations of your website pages are returning in Google Analytics. Typically, this is triggered by the use of subdomains (usually www), or your IP address if you’re experiencing DNS issues or traffic hits the IP somehow.

The bottom line is that search engines and Google Analytics do not handle subdomains in a 2014 manner. By default, the below URLs will look the same even though they are indeed different:

```
www.domain.com
blog.domain.com
anysubdomain.domain.com
domain.com
```

All will register as “/” which is your homepage.

Comment: Thanks for promptly respond! Is it possible to quick fix the redundant hostnames notification in Google Analytics?

Comment: There is a related thread here on the Google product forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/avR4kvOLG4M

Comment: This "answer" was copied from http://www.trevorayers.com/redundant-hostnames-notification-google-analytics-fix/ you can go to original source for more detail and fixes